# Trigonometric Equation - $\sin(a)+\cos(a)=1.2$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin(a) + \cos(a) = 1.2 $$
Find $$\sin(a)\cdot\cos(a)$$

I honestly have no clue how to approach this problem.
Some insight would be nice.

Comment: Square both sides.

Comment: Thank you. I got sin(a)cos(a) = .22

Comment: May I ask how you knew how to solve this so quickly?

Comment: Do you know the double angle formula?

Comment: @Sawas Nicolaou. using the identity $\sin^2a+\cos^2a=1$ was the first thing that occurs.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you !

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 how would the double angle formula help?

Comment: From $\sin(a)\cos(a) = 0.22$, you get $\sin(2a) = 0.44$ with the sine version of double angle formula.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$x+y=k \implies x^2+y^2+2xy=k^2.$$

Maybe in your case you know $x^2+y^2.$ And thus you can get $xy.$